# Create mysql query for getting unique records by check two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have uploads table from where I want to get unique row by comparing upload_id and user_id, if upload_id is same in two rows then check if user is unique then get all result. Please check my table in attached image

[image]

how can i get group by upload_id with two result having unique user_id.

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by myself

```
SELECT * FROM `uploads` where upload_id in (select upload_id from
uploads) group by upload_id, user_id
```

Comment: please don't use blockquotes